# Unable to add ZXing.Net.Mobile package to my Xamarin.Forms project

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, zxing, portable-class-library

I have an Xamarin.Forms project in which I want to use ZXing library for barcode scanning. However I am unable to install package ZXing.Net.Mobile and ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms into my portable project. The exception I keep getting is as follows:

**Could not install package 'ZXing.Net.Mobile 2.0.4.46'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile111', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.**

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Which targets does your PCL include? @DenisVitez

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a quick look at the package contents, and the package is not completely targeting PCL Profile 111 (.NET Framework 4.5, Windows 8, Windows Phone 8.1) according to the folder name. The portable library is located in the folder:

> lib/portable-net45+netcore45+wp8+UAP10.0+MonoAndroid403+MonoTouch10+Xamarin.iOS10

which is missing out *wpa81* (i.e. Windows Phone 8.1 *non*-Silverlight) to be compatible with PCL Profile 111.

Since *netcore45* and *UAP10.0* **are** included in the folder name, I suspect that the missing *wpa81* specification is just an oversight by the package authors and could be added to the folder name without problems. Of course, this has to be confirmed with the package authors, and they would need to update the NuGet package.

As a side note, I also believe the folder name is a little bit "overdone". For maximum compatibility, I think it would be better to exclude the UAP and Xamarin specifications. NuGet targets these platforms automatically if [standard](http://embed.plnkr.co/03ck2dCtnJogBKHJ9EjY/preview) *lib* folder naming conventions are used.

Comment: Is there any fix I can use to install ZXing library other than contacting package authors?

Comment: One quick-and-dirty fix would be to make a direct reference to the PCL *ZXing.Net.Mobile* assembly by browsing to the *lib/portable...* folder and add the reference manually. If the NuGet package is not already added to your solution, you can fetch the package manually from the NuGet gallery and unzip it. I honestly think that the PCL library is capable of targeting Profile 111, so adding a manual reference *should* work.

Comment: Did it work? Don't hesitate to upvote and accept the answer in that case :-)

Comment: Hi Anders, I tried changing the PCL Profile to Profile 7 and it is now working successfully. I thought this to be a better option than to manual referecing the library since I don't actually need wpa8.1. Thank you for your help with pointing to the origin of the problem with wpa8.1 support.

Comment: @AndersGustafsson I can confirm adding the reference manually works. I was able to install it in my solution to Android and iOS, so thankfully didn't need to download and unzip manually

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need Windows Phone 8.1, as per [Denis Vitez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4478466/denis-vitez) comment above, changing to Profile 7 allows you to install ZXing.Net.Mobile and ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.