# In UWP: Xamarin.Forms ZXing barcode scanning leads to exception when rotating

Tags: xamarin, win-universal-app, xamarin.forms, uwp, zxing

I'm currently developing a **barcode-scanning** Xamarin.Forms Project for iOS, Android and Universal Windows using ZXing for Forms.

The scan works just fine in Android and iOS project, but in **UWP it won't work**:

First, scanning only works, when I do it in landscape-orientation. In portrait no barcode can be scanned.

Second, everytime I finish scanning (both by cancelling and by scanning Barcode correctly) the app crashes **when I rotate the device**.

The exception: "The stream number provided was invalid.\r\nPreviewState"    System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

I'm launching the scan as simple as possible:

```
async void scan(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var scanPage = new ZXingScannerPage();

    scanPage.OnScanResult += (result) => {

        scanPage.IsScanning = false;

        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
            Navigation.PopAsync();
            DisplayAlert("Scanned Barcode", result.Text, "OK");
        });
    };

    await Navigation.PushAsync(scanPage);
}
```

Xamarin.Forms v2.3.0.49, ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms v2.0.4.46.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: how did you make it work in portrait mode? If there is not other additional code work, seems like I can't reproduce it on Lumia 640

Comment: Scanning doesn't work in portrait-mode. Actually the scanPage launches, but I'm not able to scan any barcode.

Comment: have you tried its official sample: https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile/tree/master/Samples/WindowsUniversal I can't reproduce your issue on my side, please tell us the details how to repro it

Comment: Before scanning the user navigates through a couple of different pages (Login-> MainMenu -> Page from where the scan is launched). Before scanning changing orientation is possible in any of these pages without a problem. But after scanning the reported exception is thrown when rotating the device (even when I debug with the Visual Studio Simulator).  I tried the official Froms sample: https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile/blob/master/Samples/Forms/Core/HomePage.cs

Comment: Additional Info: When I tried to add the ZXing NuGet Package when starting to develop the application the Installation failed. the error was following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37652809/unable-to-add-zxing-net-mobile-package-to-my-xamarin-forms-project   i tried to fix it by manually adding the references from the lib\portable folder. Could this be the reason?